# unable to delete kubeflow - stuck namespaces "terminating"

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy the kubeflow cluster on premise (using virtual machines).

A bit of background information first:
I followed the official guideline, with one exception - I piped the `kubectl kustomize` into a yaml file so I can peek in. The file is gargantuan (130k lines) so manually reading it is not really an option.
The deployment was partially successful, but it appears that not all resources are generated - mostly around persistent volumes needed by many services. I dug deeper and noticed there's no storageclass defined at all. After defining one I tried deleting the cluster `k delete -f manifest.yaml` and it's all stuck terminating.

### Cue of the problem

There are multiple custom resources hanging from kubeflow deployment, but I'll stick to one namespace assuming if it's fixed, I can fix remaining ones the same way.

```
root@k8s-master:/mnt/nfs_dir# k get ns
NAME                        STATUS        AGE
auth                        Terminating   17h
```

```
root@k8s-master:/mnt/nfs_dir# k get profiles.kubeflow.org -n auth
NAME                        AGE
kubeflow-user-example-com   19h
```

and describing the custom resource:

```
root@k8s-master:/mnt/nfs_dir# k describe profiles.kubeflow.org
Name:         kubeflow-user-example-com
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  kubeflow.org/v1
Kind:         Profile
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:             2024-02-13T13:23:31Z
  Deletion Grace Period Seconds:  0
  Deletion Timestamp:             2024-02-13T14:53:45Z
  Finalizers:
    profile-finalizer
  Generation:        3
  Resource Version:  4832771
  UID:               6db73d43-6f5c-43d7-9bef-eb2c0ccef775
Spec:
  Owner:
    Kind:  User
    Name:  user@example.com
  Resource Quota Spec:
Events:  <none>
```

[kubeflow repository](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/blob/master/components/profile-controller/controllers/profile_controller.go) has the reference here, but I don't know if anything is wrong with it (i don't expect it to be so)

### Question:

How do I correctly terminate the cluster without force deleting namespaces and/or custom resources?